# Counting integer solutions for a system of (in)equalities

Tags: combinatorics, diophantine-equations

I wish to enumerate the number of solutions of the system of equations and inequalities for 3 non-negative integer unknowns $x,y,z \ge 0$: ($a$,$b$ specified)
\begin{align}
x+y+z&=a\\
x+y&>b\\
y+z&>b
\end{align}

Is there an elegant way of finding the number of solutions or must I use an exhaustive numerical algorithm. Actually, further on I'll have more complicated systems of this type with more unknowns and more inequalities.

Comment: The title is entirely uninformative, and the tag doesn't seem particularly helpful either. At the very least, please fix this title.

Answer (score 1):

You are counting the lattice point in a triangle, and the magic words are [Pick's Theorem](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/background/countingLecture/pick/pick/) In higher dimensions, the question is higher, see the answer to this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10266/counting-lattice-points-on-an-n-simplex

Comment: Thank you very much. As I am far from acquainted with simplex theory, I'll have to look into that. In any case, I don't need the actual solutions but only how many of them exist for such a system.

Answer (score 1):

We may suppose that $b\in \{-1,0,1,\dots,a-1\}.$

We consider the plane $(x,z)$, your bounds are $x+z\leqslant a$, $0\leqslant x,z<a-b$. Now fix $x$, then $z$ varies from 0 to $\min(a-x,a-b-1)$. So, for $x\leqslant b$ there are $a-b$ ways to choose $z$, and for $a\geqslant x\geqslant b+1$ there exist $a-x+1$ ways to choose $z$. Totally we get $(b+1)(a-b)+(a-b)(a-b+1)/2=(a-b)(a+b+3)/2$ solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll have to check various cases and it seems that it will work.